# TYPO3 - Where do i need to put script files to be @imported

Tags: configuration, typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

In the TYPO3 backend, in the *Web* -> *Template* Section, in a template´s *Setup* text entry, I want to [include a typoscript](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/TypoScriptSyntax/Syntax/Includes.html#typoscript-syntax-includes) using the `@import` syntax.

I have setup my local Typo3 v9.5.5 test instance (Windows) inside a folder `typo3`, which itself is inside of the `htdocs` folder (it is a XAMPP installation). So the url to the backend is `http://localhost/typo3/typo3/index.php`, notice the duplication of `typo3`. The reason is, i have set up a few CMSes in the htdocs folder, each within a folder having the corresponding name.

**Where do i have to put the script inside of the typo3 folder, and what would be the correct code line which includes it?**

I tried all kind of paths, like `@import 'EXT:typo3testsite/TypoScript/playaround.typoscript'`, and putting the script under `htdocs/typo3/TypoScript/playaround.typoscript` or under `htdocs/typo3/typo3conf/sites/typo3testsite/TypoScript/playaround.typoscript`, but no success.

The site ID, set up under *Site Managment* -> *Sites*, is `typo3testsite`.

The script content, for now, is

```
page = PAGE
page.10 = TEXT
page.10.value = Hello World
```

When i have cleared constants and setup from parent templates i get *Service Unavailable (503)*. When i put the code directly into the *Setup* entry it correctly shows 'Hello World' on the front page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
# Import a single file
@import 'EXT:myproject/Configuration/TypoScript/randomfile.typoscript'

# Import multiple files in a single directory, sorted by file name
@import 'EXT:myproject/Configuration/TypoScript/*.typoscript'

# Import all files in a directory
@import 'EXT:myproject/Configuration/TypoScript/'

# It's possible to omit the file ending, then "typoscript" is automatically added
@import 'EXT:myproject/Configuration/TypoScript/'
```

See [New syntax for importing TypoScript files](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/9.0/Feature-82812-NewSyntaxForImportingTypoScriptFiles.html)

The example is useful, when you have an own extension. 'myproject' is then the name of your extension. After 'EXT:' comes the path to the configuration file in your extension.

If you have never built an own extension: [Developing TYPO3 Extensions with Extbase and Fluid](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/4-FirstExtension/1-the-example-extension.html)

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would store your TypoScript files in a custom extension here;
`http://localhost/typo3/typo3conf/ext/customTemplates/Configuration/TypoScript/Setup.ts`

(you can give "customTemplates" any name you like)

You can then include that in the TYPO3 Backend like this:

`<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:typo3conf/ext/customTemplates/Configuration/TypoScript/Setup.ts">`

__

*edit:*
Since TYPO3 v9.0 there's a simplified import statement.
The following is from the TYPO3 Changelog documentation.
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/9.0/Feature-82812-NewSyntaxForImportingTypoScriptFiles.html

```
# Import a single file
@import 'EXT:myproject/Configuration/TypoScript/randomfile.typoscript'

# Import multiple files in a single directory, sorted by file name
@import 'EXT:myproject/Configuration/TypoScript/*.typoscript'

# Import all files in a directory
@import 'EXT:myproject/Configuration/TypoScript/'

# It's possible to omit the file ending, then "typoscript" is automatically added
@import 'EXT:myproject/Configuration/TypoScript/'
```

Comment: thanks, this works, but could you put the information into your answer, how it is done using the `@import` syntax?